How to customize y-axis labels with steps - not the same size - in R, to zoom in by also changing the scales of the axis
I have a question. Since i'm very new to R and data visualisation, I hope I can ask correctly.
I'm trying to visualize a 0 - 100% simple barchart but the part between 60 - 100% is the most interesting to zoom in to.  I've tried a few things to change the steps of the Y axis like this:
0 , 20 , 40 , 60 , 70 , 80 , 90 , 100 .
The goal is to see like the whole graph from 0 - 100 %, but just to visualize the (in the images RED) difference between Rejected by Year more. Since the difference is only 4%.
I did try with scale_y_continuous to change the breaks and it did change, but not the way i'm looking for:
The result is R just showing the labels like I asked, but without changing the scales of the axis.
It's giving me this:

What I want to achieve is this:

I also did try with scale_y_break(c(0, 60)) but then the 0 - 60% disappears.
Dummy data:
status          count       %      year

Rejected       1049        14%     2024
Approved       6621        86%     2024
Rejected       1963        18%     2023
Approved       8781        82%     2023

Is there a way to customize the Y axis labels by also changing the scales?
Many thanks in advance from this newbie.

This is how I would do it:
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~status, ~count, ~pct, ~year,
  "Rejected", 1049, 0.14, 2024,
  "Approved", 6621, 0.86, 2024, 
  "Rejected", 1963, 0.18, 2023,
  "Approved", 8781, 0.82, 2023
) %>% 
  mutate(
    year = factor(year, levels = c(2023, 2024)),
    status = factor(status, levels = c("Rejected", "Approved"))
  )

df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(y = year, x = pct, fill = status)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", orientation = "y", position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE))+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(seq(0, .5, 0.1), seq(0.6, 1, .2)),
    labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1, scale = 100)
    )+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Approved" = "#016599", "Rejected" = "#990001"))

